# How to replace white spaces to &nbsp; between end of tag and start of text

Tags: c#, regex

I am using c# `regex.replace` to replace white spaces to `&nbsp;`, for example:

```
text: "<a href="foo"></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; Some text..."
```

The text after replace must be:

```
"<a href="foo"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some text..."
```

I've tried using `(?=(a>))(\s)*(?=[A-Za-z0-9&])`, but it doesn't work.

Edit: That template can be more than one time in the text, but always start with new paragraph.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? why not just normal `String.Replace`

Comment: @DavidPilkington That would also replace the spaces inside the tag, e.g. `<a&nbsp;href`

Comment: Ah yes you are correct

Comment: Write it in a para <p> text with space </p> instead of using &nbsp;

Comment: That template can be more than one time in the text, but always start with new paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Consider the following Regex...

```
(?<=&nbsp;)\s|\s(?=&nbsp;)
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer but its not work for me. When I tried to use that regex, I have got following result:   <a border="0" name="1"><img&nbsp;src=""&nbsp;/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some&nbsp;text

Comment: Can you provide some more sample text to test with? Thanks.

Comment: More full examples: first case: "<div><a href="foo"><img src=""/></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; Some text first...</div>".                                                               Second case: "<div><a href="foo"></a><img src=""/>&nbsp; &nbsp; Some text second...</div>"

Comment: Updated the answer above.

Comment: @Dmitry maybe you should use XmlReader or XmlDocument? it will parse all tags automatically

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that:

- You don't have any other closing tags after the text
- You have only `&nbsp;` after closing tag and before text
- Your text starts with letter or number

there is the code:

```
        var input = "<a href=\"foo\"></a> &nbsp; &nbsp; Some text...";
        int startIndex = input.LastIndexOf(">") + 1;

        int endIndex = startIndex;
        while (true)
        {
            if(char.IsLetterOrDigit(input[endIndex]))
                break;
            if (input[endIndex] == '&')
                endIndex += 5;
            else
                endIndex++;
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(input.Substring(0, startIndex));
        sb.Append(input.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex).Replace(" ", "&nbsp;"));
        sb.Append(input.Substring(endIndex));
```

Comment: Sorry, but that text can be more than one time